# Calculating consecutive number of dry days in year using Time Series in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, time-series

I have a database with daily raster maps of future precipitation for some years (let's say 2020-2050, divided in 10 years subperiods), named like this:

"pr_model_rcp_2020_2030.1", "pr_model_rcp_2020_2030.2", ..., "pr_model_rcp_2020_2030.3650", starting from 01/01/2020 (raster n.1) to 12/31/2030 (raster n. 3650), for the first ten years. "Model" is the model chosen for projection, "rcp" is the emission scenario.

I want to calculate the maximum number of consecutive dry days (pr < 1mm) per year.

How can I use time series command on grass or temporal aggregation (t.rast.series) to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Using TGRASS you can do that in two steps:

1. Create a weekly mask with 1 or 0 according to the desired condition:

`t.rast.aggregate input=... output=weekly_mask basename=mask_week granularity="1 weeks" method=count`

2. Calculate consecutive days of desired parameter:

`t.rast.algebra base=... expression="consecutive_days = \ weekly_mask {+,contains,l} if(dataset < 0 && dataset[-1] < 0 \ || dataset[1] < 0 && dataset < 0, 1, 0)"`

You find an example here:

https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Temporal_data_processing#How_to_count_consecutive_days_that_meet_a_certain_condition.3F

Comment: Thank you markusN. I'm working at it now. I don't know much about masks, but cannot I just calculate consecutive days without step 1? What is it useful to?

Comment: Step one is needed to generate a time reference. I believe it is not much more than copy-pasting it (with the proper names)...

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate max drought for 1 year with something like this (untested):

```
r.mapcalc "this_drought_len = 0"
r.mapcalc "max_drought_len = 0"
for doy in $(seq -w 365); do
   r.mapcalc "this_drought_len = if(pr_${doy} < 1, this_drought_len + 1, 0)"
   r.mapcalc "max_drought_len = max(max_drought_len, this_drought_len)"
done
```

Just wrap that loop in your year loop. I agree that the GRASS Temporal Framework should probably be used, but sometimes I find it quicker to use loops instead.

Note that these two `r.mapcalc` commands have the same variable on LHS and RHS. That is not allowed according to the docs. When I test it, it does not have any bugs, but it might be better to assign to a temp variable and then rename with overwrite on the next line.

Note that this method won't capture long droughts spanning new years.

Running this in parallel for each year and RCP (but sequential per day) looks like this:

```
RCP="2.6 4.5 8.5"
YEAR=$(seq 2020 2050)
parallel "r.mapcalc \"this_{1}_{2} = 0\"" ::: ${RCP} ::: ${YEAR}
parallel "r.mapcalc \"max_{1}_{2} = 0\"" ::: ${RCP} ::: ${YEAR}
for doy in $(seq -w 365); do
   parallel "r.mapcalc \"this_{1}_{2} = if(pr_${RCP}_${YEAR}.${doy} < 1, this_{1}_{2} + 1, 0)\"" ::: ${RCP} ::: ${YEAR}
   parallel "r.mapcalc \"max_{1}_{2} = max(max_{1}_{2}, this_{1}_{2})\"" ::: ${RCP} ::: ${YEAR}
done
```